# Open folder using variable Path

Tags: excel, vba, path, directory

I am trying to open the folder where the macro workbook is located.

In this example, it is in folder "H:\Projects\IWA_Populate". However, the workbook could be in any folder location.

If I specify a static path as below it opens to the target folder IWA_Populate:

```
Shell "explorer.exe H:\Projects\IWA_Populate", vbNormalFocus
```

However if I replace the path with a variable as such below it only opens My Documents folder.

```
Shell "explorer.exe file_path", vbNormalFocus
```

Here is my code to get file_path initialized:

```
Public file_path As String
Public xl As Excel.Application
Set xl = Application: xl.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
file_path = xl.ActiveWorkbook.Path
'Shell "explorer.exe H:\Projects\IWA_Populate", vbNormalFocus
Shell "explorer.exe file_path", vbNormalFocus
MsgBox file_path
```

The Message box is to test that `file_path` is set to the correct full path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move `file_path` *outside* the quotation marks and use the ampersand `&`. While it's inside the quotation marks, it is no longer the variable `file_path`, but the `String` literal `"file_path"`.

Change:

```
Shell "explorer.exe file_path", vbNormalFocus
```

to

```
Shell "explorer.exe " & file_path, vbNormalFocus
```

---

**EDIT**: As @TimWilliams pointed out, you can adjust this to

```
Shell "explorer.exe """ & file_path & """", vbNormalFocus
```

to allow for spaces in the file name.

Comment: Hi Ben, Quick question would 

Shell "explorer.exe " & file_path, vbNormalFocus

be different if my path contained a space? Like:
H:\Projects\IWA Populate

Comment: `Shell "explorer.exe """ & file_path & """", vbNormalFocus` will allow for spaces in the folder path